# WCF client throwing error : The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message

Tags: rest, wcf

I have one of my WCF service running in production which I wanted to expose it also as Rest service so other client can use via rest endpoints.

The existing client are configured to use as basicHttpBinding And for new client for rest webHttpBinding.

After adding required changes for webHttpBinding the existing client started giving error because as part of change I have removed [Serializable] and use [DataContract] so I can correct json properties.

Below is the error :

System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:MySomeMethodResult. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 2647. 'EndElement' 'MySomeMethodResult' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' is not expected. Expecting element '_x003C_MyPropertyName_x003E_k__BackingField'.'. Please see InnerException for more details. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 2647. 'EndElement' 'MySomeMethodResult' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' is not expected. Expecting element '_x003C_MyPropertyName_x003E_k__BackingField'

Below are WCF Service Configuration :

```
<behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="webBehaviour">
                <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"
                 automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" faultExceptionEnabled="true" />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>             
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

        <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Default" closeTimeout="00:24:00" openTimeout="00:24:00" receiveTimeout="00:24:00" sendTimeout="00:24:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="21474836470" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="SecureHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:24:00" openTimeout="00:24:00" receiveTimeout="00:24:00" sendTimeout="00:24:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="21474836470" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <!--RESTFul webHttpBinding-->
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WebHttpBinding_Default">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"></transport>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
        <!--RESTFul webHttpBinding-->
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
        <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="SecureHttpBinding" />
    </protocolMapping>

<services>
            <service name="MyBigApp.SometManagement.Ui.Authentication">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyBigApp.SometManagement.Shared.ServiceInterfaces.IAuthentication"
                 bindingConfiguration="SecureHttpBinding"   
                />
                <endpoint address="api" behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour"
                 binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_Default"
                 contract="MyBigApp.SometManagement.Shared.ServiceInterfaces.IAuthentication" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="https://localhost/MyBigApp.SometManagement.Ui/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
```

Sample class

```
[DataContract] // All are working fine with  [Serializable] on existing client but rest is not giving correct json response with  [Serializable]  
public class MyAppDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

Not sure what configuration I am missing here , Any guidance will be really appreciated.

My Main goal is to expose the same service as rest as well without affecting existing client who has consumed this service.

Comment: The problem with deserialization failures is typically because the XML elements are out of order. I suggest that you can adjust the order with the "Order" attribute in your code, or directly adjust the order sent by the client. Also check to see if there are private properties.